# HDMI turns off after few seconds in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

When I use capture card for display output it works fine but when i use monitor with HDMI output turns off after 2-3 seconds in Raspberry Pi 4

Comment: what is your question? ... what troubleshooting have you done? ... please, do not assume that when you say `I have a problem with ABC`, that it is actually a question about ABC

Comment: maybe a failing monitor